# keycloak token introspection always fails with {"active":false}

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm kind of desesperate to make this keycloak work. I can authenticate but for some reason, my token introspection always fail.
For example if I try to authenticate:

```
curl -d 'client_id=flask_api' -d 'client_secret=98594477-af85-48d8-9d95-f3aa954e5492' -d 'username=jean@gmail.com' -d 'password=superpassE0' -d 'grant_type=password' 'http://keycloak.dev.local:9000/auth/realms/skilltrock/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

I get my access_token as expected:

```
{
   "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJnLVZJQ0VETnJ4NWRfN1pWQllCTC1tNDdTZWFNT3NDVlowSFdtZF9QQkZrIn0.eyJqdGkiOiIwNTBkYWI5MS1kMjA5LTQwYjctOTBkOS1mYTgzMWYyMTk1Y2MiLCJleHAiOjE1NDQ1MjIyNDEsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTQ0NTIxOTQxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8va2V5Y2xvYWsuZGV2LmxvY2FsOjkwMDAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvc2tpbGx0cm9jayIsImF1ZCI6ImFjY291bnQiLCJzdWIiOiI3NDA0MWNkNS1lZDBhLTQzMmYtYTU3OC0wYzhhMTIxZTdmZTAiLCJ0eXAiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJhenAiOiJmbGFza19hcGkiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjAsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiJiOGI0MzA2Ny1lNzllLTQxZmItYmNkYi0xMThiMTU2OWU3ZDEiLCJhY3IiOiIxIiwicmVhbG1fYWNjZXNzIjp7InJvbGVzIjpbIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIiwidW1hX2F1dGhvcml6YXRpb24iXX0sInJlc291cmNlX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJhY2NvdW50Ijp7InJvbGVzIjpbIm1hbmFnZS1hY2NvdW50IiwibWFuYWdlLWFjY291bnQtbGlua3MiLCJ2aWV3LXByb2ZpbGUiXX19LCJzY29wZSI6ImVtYWlsIHByb2ZpbGUiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsIm5hbWUiOiJqZWFuIHBpZXJyZSIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImplYW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6ImplYW4iLCJmYW1pbHlfbmFtZSI6InBpZXJyZSIsImVtYWlsIjoiamVhbkBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.x1jW1cTSWSXN5DsXT3zk1ra4-BcxgjXbbqV5cjdwKTovoNQn7LG0Y_kR8-8Pe8MvFe7UNmqrHbHh21wgZy1JJFYSnnPKhzQaiT5YTcXCRybSdgXAjnvLpBjVQGVbMse_obzjjE1yTdROrZOdf9ARBx6EBr3teH1bHMu32a5wDf-fpYYmHskpW-YoQZljzNyL353K3bmWMlWSGzXx1y7p8_T_1WLwPMPr6XJdeZ5kW0hwLcaJVyDhX_92CFSHZaHQvI8P095D4BKLrI8iJaulnhsb4WqnkUyjOvDJBqrGxPvVqJxC4C1NXKA4ahk35tk5Pz8uS33HY6BkcRKw7z6xuA",
   "expires_in":300,
   "refresh_expires_in":1800,
   "refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJlYmY4ZDVlOC01MTM4LTRiNTUtYmZhNC02YzcwMzBkMTIwM2YifQ.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.omhube2oe79dXlcChOD9AFRdUep53kKPjD0HF14QioY",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "not-before-policy":0,
   "session_state":"b8b43067-e79e-41fb-bcdb-118b1569e7d1",
   "scope":"email profile"
}
```

But if I try to introspect the access_token like given below, keycloack return always {"active":false}. I really don't understand this behavior.

```
curl -X POST -u "flask_api:98594477-af85-48d8-9d95-f3aa954e5492" -d "token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJnLVZJQ0VETnJ4NWRfN1pWQllCTC1tNDdTZWFNT3NDVlowSFdtZF9QQkZrIn0.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.x1jW1cTSWSXN5DsXT3zk1ra4-BcxgjXbbqV5cjdwKTovoNQn7LG0Y_kR8-8Pe8MvFe7UNmqrHbHh21wgZy1JJFYSnnPKhzQaiT5YTcXCRybSdgXAjnvLpBjVQGVbMse_obzjjE1yTdROrZOdf9ARBx6EBr3teH1bHMu32a5wDf-fpYYmHskpW-YoQZljzNyL353K3bmWMlWSGzXx1y7p8_T_1WLwPMPr6XJdeZ5kW0hwLcaJVyDhX_92CFSHZaHQvI8P095D4BKLrI8iJaulnhsb4WqnkUyjOvDJBqrGxPvVqJxC4C1NXKA4ahk35tk5Pz8uS33HY6BkcRKw7z6xuA" http://localhost:9000/auth/realms/skilltrock/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
```

return

```
{"active":false}
```

Where I am wrong? I'm totally lost

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to make sure that you introspect the token using the same DNS hostname/port as the request. Unfortunately that's a not widely documented "feature" of Keycloak...
So use:

```
   curl -u "flask_api:98594477-af85-48d8-9d95-f3aa954e5492" -d "token=<token>" http://keycloak.dev.local:9000/auth/realms/skilltrock/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
```

Comment: can you please elaborate in case of accesstoken being requested by a party on a different machine and introspected by a service on a different machine?? Also please if you know how to do it via authzclient in java for keycloak

Comment: Just realized the answer to my question as soon as i posted the comment.Sometimes happens when you are having a long day. Cheers Hans Z man you really nailed it.

Comment: @JayD I am having the same issue. Could you please share how you solved it, I mean introspect with a different hostname and port?

Comment: @edkeveked just like it is mentioned in the answer you have to use the same auth server url which you used for generating the token

Comment: @edkeveked take a close look at op's question when introspecting he has used localhost instead of the hostname used while generating the token, same was the case with me as soon as i used the same hostname that was used to generate the token my problem got solved

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks

Comment: Can't upvote this enough.  Same holds true for OpenIddict.  I was issuing the token on HTTPS and introspecting it on HTTP....

Comment: its the issuer that changes...

Comment: For people coming across this issue for the first time, I recommend you to also check @dschulten 's answer. Specifically, the section recommending setting the "Frontend URL" for the realm in the Keycloak admin UI. This solved the issue for me without trying to figure out how all of my clients in different environments could use the same hostname and port to communicate with Keycloak.

Answer (score 5):

A legacy alternative is to send a `Host` header with the introspection request which matches the frontend host where the token was obtained. That I have tried, I can confirm that it works. It requires configuration of two URLs for the introspecting protected resource, though.

Since Keycloak 8 it is also possible to use the OpenID Connect Discovery as described in https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-11728 and the attached design document.

The latter solution involves two things:

1. Keycloak needs to know the frontend URL used for token retrieval by clients; that can happen at start time as described in the [server installation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#default-provider) (-Dkeycloak.frontendUrl or standalone.xml) or when definining a realm through its **Frontend URL** Option in the Keycloak Management UI. The Keycloak docker container supports the [environment variable](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/10.0.2/server/README.md#misc) KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL for this. Note that the frontendUrl needs to include the basePath where Keycloak is running (/auth by default, adjust as needed).
2. Optionally, the protected resource can use OIDC discovery to determine the introspection URL. Either use the Keycloak Java Adapter >=v8 which has built-in support for OIDC Discovery or verify if your protected resource does. See the [related PR on the Keycloak Java Adapter](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6412) for details.

When a protected resource uses the internal discovery endpoint http://keycloak:8998/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration, it will find the correct internal introspection endpoint:

```
{
  "issuer": "http://localhost:8998/auth/realms/myrealm",
  "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8998/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "token_introspection_endpoint": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
}
```

Using the discovery endpoint is not required. If you just need to introspect an incoming token with Keycloak, you can directly use the introspection endpoint.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this answer, that was a big time saver!

Answer (score 4):

The introspect endpoint can also return `{"active":false}` if a session associated with that token doesn't exist in Keycloak. For example, if you create the token, restart keycloak and then call introspect.

Comment: how can I force returning challenge in that case, or something to force user re-log in?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned earlier the same domain should be used when obtaining and introspecting the token.

For me, I was using the `localhost` to obtain the token and 127.0.0.1 to introspect the token.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to set the FRONTEND URL attribute to the same DNS. If you're developing locally got to the Realm Settings and set Frontend URL attribute to `http://localhost:<port>` and you're good to go.